# postgresql Modifying existing unique index

Tags: postgresql, index, unique-constraint

I have this table on PostgreSQL:

```
example_dev=# \d products
                                    Table "public.products"
 Column |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |               Default                
--------+------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------
 id     | bigint                 |           | not null | nextval('products_id_seq'::regclass)
 name   | character varying(255) |           |          | 
 price  | integer                |           |          | 
 sku    | character varying(255) |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "products_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "name_price_unique_index" UNIQUE, btree (name, price)
```

As you see, I have a combined unique key `name_price_unique_index` on the columns `name` and `price`.

What I need to do is to modify this because I need to add `sku` column too. So I'd be needing a combination of the three columns.

Somthing like this:

```
"name_price_sku_unique_index" UNIQUE, btree (name, price, sku)
```

I've been looking for info on how to do this but I haven't found any.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new index and replace the old one:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY newidx ON tab (name, price, sku);
DROP INDEX name_price_sku_unique_index;
ALTER INDEX newidx RENAME TO name_price_sku_unique_index;
```